how to only trigger push on push and not on branch merge after pull request
I have a github workflow, which trigger on push. If there is a PR and branch is merged, I don't want it to be triggered. Need advice on how to do that.
My current code below does not work because github.event.pull_request.merged is only applicable or have value when the on trigger is pr.
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test

jobs:
  do_not_run_on_merged:
    if: (github.event.pull_request.merged == false)
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo This is not a merge
  


If you always use the default merge commit message, you could use a job-level condition that looks like this:
jobs:
  do_not_run_on_merged:
    if: "!startsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, 'Merge ')"

For a more robust approach that doesn't rely on commit message formatting, you have to actually run at least one step to check. You could use the REST API to get the latest commit, and look at the number of parents it has (merge commits have more than one parent):
jobs:
  check_if_merged:
    runs-on: ubuntu-24.04
    outputs:
      is_merged: ${{ steps.check.outputs.is_merged }}
    steps:
      - name: Check if merge commit
        id: check
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: |
          parents=$(gh api "repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/commits/$GITHUB_SHA" \
              --jq '.parents | length')

          if ((parents > 1)); then
              echo "is_merged=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          fi

  do_not_run_on_merged:
    needs: check_if_merged
    if: needs.check_if_merged.outputs.is_merged != 'true'

This uses the GitHub CLI to make the API call, and jq to filter the response.
Instead of $GITHUB_SHA, you could also use the branch ref test, but that allows for a race condition where a new commit was pushed between the workflow starting and making the API call.

Nice, the first answer is similar to what i end up using.
Could you share more on how the 2nd answer works

@lonelearner I have expanded a bit on what the second solution does.
